# Why @Cacheable annotation leads to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, spring, rest, caching

I just added `@Cacheable(value = "testCaching", key = "#id")` to a methode in the `@RestController` as the following:

```
  @Cacheable(value = "testCaching", key = "#id")
  public Book getCachedMsg(@PathVariable("id") final int id, final HttpServletResponse response)
```

And got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [int] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.
```

Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: are you tried with "key=id"?

Comment: you mean to remove #; yes, I also did that and got the same error!

Comment: maybe the problem its because you are adding the cacheable to a Controller method, maybe would be better if from the controller, you make a call to some service with the cacheable annotation inside. Can you try that?

Comment: yes, I did that, and didnt get the error, but caching didn't work :(

Comment: I have the cacheable working in my project, but without the key, just the name, because its a getAllXX(), let me check what could be the problem. But try to use the second approach, the cacheable method in a service not in the controller

Comment: Add `@P("id)` as annotation next to the `@PathVariable`. Also adding `@Cacheable` to a controller method isn't something I would suggest doing. But that is imho of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @Cacheable(value = "testCaching", key = "#p0")
  public Book getCachedMsg(@PathVariable("id") final int id, final HttpServletResponse response)
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer ?